# Zooming is not smooth in webview inside scrollview in android

Tags: android

This is the code am using

```
 <RelativeLayout >       

    <ScrollView>
            <WebView/>                            

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: why would you put `WebView` inside `ScrollView`, when `WebView` scrolls itself

Answer (score 2):

change your code to:

```
<RelativeLayout>
       <Webview>

       </Webview>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll in Scroll is not recommended at all as creates all kinds of weird scroll behaviours. If you really need Scroll inside scroll you'll need to disable the outer scroll when the inner scroll area is selected and while the finger is down... But please try to implement your design in some other way.